# How would you implement a stock chart into an Android app?

Tags: java, android, libraries, android-developer-api

I have been looking for a way to implement dynamic stock charts into my Android app but I don't where to start. I know I'll need a library, in fact, I found two [LightWeight Charts](https://www.tradingview.com/lightweight-charts/) and [Vaadin](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow) but I don't know if they would work. I am very new to android programming and have never actually implemented a library into any project ever. I just need some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I suggest to search "stock charts" in google image to find what kind of chart you need before you choose.
2. Decompose this graph into data curve, background and scale. Maybe you have to implement them separately.
3. Find some Android library recommend web site that has the "similar lib" function which help you to find a lot of this kind libs. As I know one: https://android-arsenal.com/

My AD: https://github.com/maxyou/SimpleWaveform. It only draw a list of data to a rectangle, and you can draw any background and scale by yourself. Surely, you need to compare a lot of libs and then choose the most suitable one.